# Buffering every polygon in layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer

I'm trying to use the `"Fixed Distance Buffer"` from the Processing Toolbox to create a `500m` buffer around all the woodlands in my layer, but the tool only puts a buffer around the smaller woodlands.

How can I make it put a buffer around every attribute?

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Try fixing geometries first.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using the [v.generalize.smooth](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/v.generalize.html) GRASS plugin.

now the buffer works on every polygon.

Comment: This is the answer to the question I asked.

Comment: @Val P, why should not? I would just simply suggest the author extending his answer with some graphic and additional comments.

Comment: @Watrevir Sorry, my error. I removed the comments.